# Чтение и запись TTY

Tags: linux

Подключил мобильный телефон по **USB**, нашел **/dev/ttyACM0**, смотрю вывод с помощью инструкции

```
$ sudo cat /dev/ttyACM0
```

все нормально, вижу:

> ...
>   +CGREG: 1,"317E","000005D5"
>   ...

Открываю новый сеанс и пытаюсь передать комманду

```
$ sudo echo ATI > /dev/ttyACM0
```

получаю отказ в доступе. Делаю то же

```
$ sudo cp /dev/tty /dev/ttyACM0
```

что-то передает, но ответ модема телефона - ERROR.

Используя программу **screen**, все работает, но нет эха ввода с клавиатуры на экране. (kubuntu, console, yakuake)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто знает, это так и должно быть или нет, и что делать?

Comment: А вы при этом старый закрываете? Кто передаёт команды, которые вы видите? То есть существует ещё и программа какая-то, которая общается с модемом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> echo ATI > /dev/ttyACM0, получаю отказ в доступе

в *debian*-основных дистрибутивах по умолчанию динамически создаваемые файлы `/dev/tty*` принадлежат группе `dialout`, и у группы есть право чтения и записи.

наиболее логично будет добавить вашего пользователя в эту группу:

```
$ sudo adduser $USER dialout
```

после чего надо перелогиниться, чтобы изменение вступило в силу.

и от имени этого пользователя можно будет читать и писать в динамически создаваемые файлы `/dev/tty*`:

```
$ cat /dev/ttyACM0
...
$ echo ... > /dev/ttyACM0
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но если использовать толко cp (и для передачи и для приема) то права изменять не нужно. Все работает.

Comment: программа `cp`??? для приёма и передачи надо читать и записывать из (в) этого файла. например, с помощью пары `cat` и `echo`, или ещё многих других разных программ, в т.ч. мультиплексоров типа `screen`/`tmux`. но программа `cp` предназначена совершенно для другого.

Comment: Да, может и так. Однако копирование потока очень универсально. 
`sudo cp /dev/tty /dev/ttyACM0` в одном окне и `sudo cp /dev/ttyACM0 /dev/tty` в другом работатают "почти" как терминал.

Comment: почему «однако»? например, `echo ... > файл` — это и есть копирование потока *stdout* в файл (правда, более распространён термин «перенаправление»). а то, для чего вы используете программу `cp` — это точно не копирование потока.

Comment: Я далеко не эксперт в Linux. Но `cat` и `echo` что-то делают не так, с модемом, или портом, я не разбирался.

Comment: Это модемы телефонов ведут себя по разному, по отношению в виртуальному UART-у, почему то. Linux `cat` и `echo` ни при чем. Но что имеем, то имеем.

Answer (score 0):

Относительно программы **screen**. Она, почему-то, не поддерживает эхо. Нужно включить его, в модеме, командой `ATE`.